# stuck with spaces and arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I want to display a full name, but I can't enter more than two parts of a name. The program stuck when enter a name which has more characters than the number which array has. How can I solve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
char x[25];
printf("Enter your name");
scanf("%s",x);  
printf("Your name is %s", x);
return 0;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: `scanf("%24[^\n]", x);`

Comment: This is one of several reasons why it is recommended to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: Please format/indent your program correctly.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it works! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you. This program doesnt care how many characters, spaces you entered. It only displays first 24 characters and spaces. (1 for string terminator)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   char x[25];
   char *xx=x;
puts("Input Name");
fgets(xx,25,stdin);
puts(xx);

return 0; 
  }
```

Comment: What is the `xx`variable for ? You can use `x` directly.

Comment: Thank you! what is a string terminator?

Comment: string terminator is stored as an array,  it is unprintable

Comment: @user7030669 - By definition a _[C string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm)_ is an array of 'char' always ending with a NULL terminator, in the form of '\0', or '0'.  This is why if you need to display a string with 25 char, the string array must contain room for 26.